# KeyDown, KeyUp and KeyPressed won't fire on a WinForms app hosting an WPF control which plays video

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have a window application which host wpf control to play the video.
I want to close the application on keyperss event.

but the keydown,keyup and keypressed none of the events fires when it hosts wpf controls.

how to catch the keydown event of the form which host wpf control??

Thanking in advance..

Comment: I believe nothing special about hosting. Did you set `this.KeyPreview` to true?